# Scheduling with Network Time Server (SNTP) in Quartz .NET

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, ntp

I need to use network-validated time when scheduling jobs.

#### Solution?

- With the latest [.NET Quartz library](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html), does anyone knowledgeable in the inner workings of Quartz .NET know [which class(es) actually implement](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet) the job to start at the specified time? (details below)
- Or is there an alternative C# library / API that already supports NTP queries and that can schedule jobs?
- Please note that [using the approach of inputting the difference between local time and network time to a non-NTP scheduler does not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996835/how-use-ntp-server-when-scheduling-tasks-in-java-app) because I need to prevent users cheating by way of changing their local system time or timezone

#### Quartz .NET Details - where I got stuck in my investigation

I cannot find how the property StartTimeUtc of ITrigger is used (set with the StartAt method below)?

```
var sleepTrigger = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("SleepTimeTrigger")
            .StartAt(sleepRunTime)
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever())
            .Build();
```

i.e. I need to check the specific implementation that uses the StartTimeUtc timestamp in order to change the scheduling source code / add an option to schedule independently of local system time and use network time instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a static class under Quartz namespace which has two methods receiving a `Func<DateTimeOffset>` that you can use to return your NTP tunned date/time. It is the "official" Quartz date/time source, and is implemented to allow easy unit testing, but could also be used to customize the date/time. Here is a a sample usage:

```
SystemTime.Now = () => {
    //return your custom datetime here
    /*
    var ntpTime = new NtpTime(server);
    return ntpTime.NowDateTimeOffset;
    */
};

SystemTime.UtcNow  = () => {
    //return your custom datetime here
    /*
    var ntpTime = new NtpTime(server);
    return ntpTime.UtcNowDateTimeOffset;
    */
};
```

Notice the code above will not compile, you need to implement your own method of getting the current DateTimeOffset for both `Now` and `UtcNow`. There are many ways to get the time from a NTP, you can find some approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769118/how-to-query-date-at-time-windows-com-ntp-server-by-using-c-net-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c). I suggest that your implementation caches the current datetime and increment it locally instead of asking the ntp server on every call, for performance reasons.