# Java - Best choice to get a POSIX UTC timestamp from external server?

Tags: java, networking, time, utc

I have a Java program that needs the current date and time. This is normally easily done, but if the user's system date/time is incorrectly set it could present issues for my software.

I want to pull the current date/time from an external server, so I was thinking I could use a Java implementation of an NTP client to pull a POSIX UTC timestamp from a public NTP server (e.g. pool.ntp.org) as that's way more dependable and cost effective than me running my own server(s) for this purpose.

Is NTP a good solution here, or is there a better protocol that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used apache commons [NTP](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/package-summary.html) before which is fine, unless you're running on windows and need millisecond accuracy, in which case, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925191/java-ntp-client) answer.