# How to get the time from a server without using system time

Tags: java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class currentTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
    }

}
```

If I change my system date it will automatically change TO same time....
so... I need to show original internet server time without system time...... anyone pls ans this.......

Comment: Use NTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925191/java-ntp-client

Comment: can't get .need example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.util.Date;
 import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient; 
 import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;

     public class TimeLookup {

    public static void main() throws Exception {
                String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";   
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
        Date time = new Date(returnTime);
        System.out.println("Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + time);
    }
}
```

Try this code.. Its working

Comment: have tried .but whenever changing the system time the output also changed