# How can I get exact UTC current time stamp at time4j without usage of system timezone and system clock?

Tags: java, datetime, time, timestamp, time4j

there!

I have to get the accurate current UTC time without calling a system clock or system time zone. I need to get precise UTC time via the Time4j library.

The issue that after getting UTC time via different ways there is a mismatch in accuracy with exact UTC time in particular - a mismatch in seconds. And that is critical for me.

**I need to get exact UTC timestamp because of mismatch is more than 5 seconds on my machine and current UTC time.** I have to transmit this timestamp into API and API in his tern updates DB. I perform some actions per seconds and real situation that I can't do this because of insufficiently accurate time.

Here some examples I've tested to get current UTC timestamp:

```
Moment moment = Moment.UNIX_EPOCH;

First:
PlainTimestamp test1 = SystemClock.inZonalView("UTC").now();

Second:
Moment test2 = Moment.nowInSystemTime();

Third:
PlainTimestamp test3 = moment.toLocalTimestamp();

Forth:
PlainTimestamp test4 = Moment.nowInSystemTime().toZonalTimestamp("UTC");
```

I didn't get needed accuracy by those methods.

**Is there any methods how can I get actual UTC timestamp with very high accuracy up to seconds via time4j?**

Comment: Configure your OS to regularly synchronize its system time with an NTP server.

Comment: @JBNizet - or perhaps just get the app code to [ask an NTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925191/2144390) itself.

Comment: @GordThompson And Time4J even contains such an [SNTP-client](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/clock/SntpConnector.html) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code examples are all finally based on `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If you observe low accuracy using this simple clock then you can choose between two ways:

- Follow the advise of JB Nizet to regularly synchronize your OS with an NTP server
- Or you can use the package [net.time4j.clock](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/clock/package-summary.html) which contains alternative clocks.

Example:

```
  SntpConnector clock = new SntpConnector("ptbtime1.ptb.de"); // ntp-server-address
  clock.connect(); // requires internet connectivity, performs the synchronization
  Moment utc = clock.currentTime()); // can be called without actual internet access
```

Comment: I followed your advice about the usage of net.time4j.clock package and it worked for me. I struggled with this issue for a long time. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, the `SntpConnector` combines SNTP and `System.nanoTime()`. Other clocks like `HttpClock` also need internet connectivity and are simpler but probably also less precise.