# How to get Internet Date Instead of using System Date

Tags: java, datetime, current-time

My Need : I need to get the current Date and time from Internet ie.. not from local system

If i change the system date and time , it should not change !

Better if possible, may be any rest api to get date.
or any other idea in java .

I used TimeZone , Instant, And many other local api which returns system time and date.

I need it to be done in JAVA.

Comment: I think you are wondering for a NTP Java client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925191/java-ntp-client

Answer (score -1):

I think google already provide ntp time server for developers.

try this link https://developers.google.com/time/