# Is there an api to set ntp time server for android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, ntp

I know that from ADB, to set the time server on Android for ntp you can use the command:

```
adb shell /system/bin/settings put global ntp_server SERVER
```

Where **SERVER** would be the new ntp time server. This works fine from the command line, but I am trying to do this with code. Below is my code for a Xamarin.Forms app.  I do not believe the issue is that it is written in c# vs Java or Kotlin.

```
public void SetTimeServer(string timeServer)
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"/system/bin/settings";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"put global ntp_server {timeServer}";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Data); };
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Data); };
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

When I run this code, I see the following error:

```
[0:] Security exception: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=6567, uid=10100 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
[0:] 
[0:] 
[0:] java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=6567, uid=10100 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
[0:]    at com.android.server.am.UserController.getCurrentUser(UserController.java:1878)
[0:]    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getCurrentUser(ActivityManagerService.java:17631)
[0:]    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.onCommand(SettingsService.java:259)
[0:]    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
[0:]    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService.onShellCommand(SettingsService.java:49)
[0:]    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
[0:]    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
[0:]    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
[0:]    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Changing the code to use the Java equivalent does line:

```
        Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec($"settings put global ntp_server {timeServer}");
```

does not appear to make any difference.  It still doesn't work.

Updating AndroidManifest.xml with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
```

also does not solve the problem.

Has anyone run in to this before?  How would I solve the problem?

Comment: The primary issue here is not the permission problem, it is actually the setting of a time server for ntp.

Comment: How do you do the equivalent of "settings put global ntp_server {timeServer}" with an api call?

Comment: You are dealing with something that was configured by the ROM builder, or set via developer mode. If you don't trust device/network time you could implement your own [Java NTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925191/295004) and connect to a trusted NTP server. You may want to explain why you need to set NTP server programmatically.

Comment: The device firmware was built in house by my employer.  Changing the default ntp server will not help.  We are building an "appliance" that is a custom Android device running AOSP, but deployed on site at our customers' locations.  Internet may or may not be accessible.  Time for the device needs to be in sync, meaning using same time server, with local webservers at customer sites.  This is why we need to change the time server.  We cannot do it in the Android build.  Manual work around is connect to the devices through adb and run the exact same command the app is trying to run.

Comment: Either I need to solve the permission issue to allow the existing command to work or I need to find a different solution to accomplish the same thing, which is keep the time of the devices in sync with the time of the local webservers.

Comment: you may get more useful responses [here](https://android.stackexchange.com).  Describing the scenario you are dealing with in the original post would be a good idea.

Comment: AOSP is quite locked down as you have found out. I would check with the ROM builders to see if there is 'root' or other way to get elevated rights like the app being signed with the OEM key. Ideally a system level app to change NTP server should be in custom appliance, https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/perms-allowlist , https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time/network-time-detection , https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/time/external-time-detection

Comment: There are three different errors I ran in to.  To solve the errors and allow app to set the time server, the app needs to be a system app.  The app also needs the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:
      <permission name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
      <permission name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
      <permission name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
      <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />

It may be necessary to grant such permissions to the app in a permissions xml file stored in /etc/permissions